# Could a natural satellite in geosynchronous orbit be used as a counterweight to a space elevator?

Tags: planets, physics, moons, space-elevators, geophysics

Could a natural satellite in geosynchronous orbit be used as a counterweight for a space elevator? Does the counterweight need to be of approximately the same weight as the anchor? If so, I suppose that would be one hell of an anchor.

I'm envisioning an inhabited alien world on which the resident civilization decides to build a space elevator. Could they use the natural satellite as part in parcel of the project? Could it be the counterweight? Or, as one of the answerers indicated, could it be inserted as a point along the elevator itself.

Comment: This question is **much** better suited to Physics.SE or Space.SE.  Besides, exact station keeping is required, and natural satellites can't do that.

Comment: No, it needs to be farther out. But you can use the satellite as a building station. In whatever orbit you are, you are in free fall anyway, so weight considerations do not apply much. You must take into account the fact that until the farther-out counterweight is installed, every elevator run changes the satellite orbit a tiny bit. In that sense, the more massive the satellite, the better.

Comment: So you're saying that the elevator could essentially "run through" the satellite and then continue onward, past the satellite, to a counterweight which is quite a bit further out?

Comment: if you had put a little tiny effort in googling you would have found a tidy answer to your very question. VTC.

Comment: I don't think so. Googling would not have turned up the concept that a geosynchronous natural satellite could have been a halfway point for a space elevator. Very valuable world-building concept that likely would only turn up in a forum like this.

Comment: you don't think, but you didn't try. Wikipedia has a picture illustrating exactly this very concept.

Comment: I think it's a little early to put this on hold. All of the answers or cited references are concerned with a space elevator to an artificial satellite in geosynchronous orbit, which would not be massive enough to serve as an anchor and would require a counterweight. None have anything to do with a natural satellite, which would presumably provide a mass of an entirely different scale.

Comment: What is the difference between "a natural satellite in geosynchronous orbit" and "a planet tidally locked to one of its moons"? Unless the natural satellite is an unnaturally tiny speck of a thing, we should be asking about using it as an anchor, not as a counterweight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but the counterweight has to be *past* the geosynchronous orbit. Sort of like a cat's tail. The point of geosynchronous orbit is the fulcrum on which the whole elevator will balance.